# jquery sortable remove next row before sorting

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have one table containing `parent` and `child` as below. `parent` are sortable. When I try to sort any parent, I've to remove it's next `child` and insert it after it's new position.

```
<table>
    <tr class="parent"><td>Parent1</td></tr>
    <tr class="child nosort"><td>Child1</td></tr>
    <tr class="parent"><td>Parent2</td></tr>
    <tr class="child nosort"><td>Child2</td></tr>
    <tr class="parent"><td>Parent3</td></tr>
    <tr class="child nosort"><td>Child3</td></tr>
</table>
```

So if I move Parent1 after Parent2, it will look:

```
<table>       
    <tr class="parent"><td>Parent2</td></tr>
    <tr class="child nosort"><td>Child2</td></tr>
    <tr class="parent"><td>Parent1</td></tr>
    <tr class="child nosort"><td>Child1</td></tr>
    <tr class="parent"><td>Parent3</td></tr>
    <tr class="child nosort"><td>Child3</td></tr>
</table>
```

I've done with the insertion of child after `sortupdate` but not able to figure out how to remove child row before sort. Below if code written on `start`.

```
$('table').sortable({
    items: 'tr:not(.nosort)',
    start: function( event, ui ) {
        // Removal code of child before sort
        var objChild = ui.item.next();
        if( objChild.hasClass('child') ) {
            objChild.remove();
        }
    },
    update: function( event, ui ) {
    //  insertion code of child
    }
});
```

Comment: Why didn't you simply used two `<div>` inside your one `<td>`?..

Comment: You can place "Parent" right before or right after another Parent, so your issue (which I think you're very aware of) is not only "How to remove or *move* it's Child", but also how to move a child that is not related to the dragged element. (i.e: move Parent1 between Parent2 and Child2... what should happen to Child2?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer *exactly* what you asked:

- Store the next elements into `data-*` attribute of each `.parent`
- On sortable `start` event use Use [jQuery's `.detach()`](https://api.jquery.com/detach/) to store the child element(s) into data.
- On sortable `stop` event use `.after()` ti insert the previously detached elements

```js
$('.parent').each(function(i, e) {
   $(this).data('$next', $(this).nextUntil('.parent'));
});

$('table').sortable({
  items: 'tr:not(.nosort)',
  start: function( ev, ui ) {
    $next = $(ui.item.data('$next')).detach();    
  },
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    ui.item.after($next);
  }
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="parent"><td>1 Parent</td></tr>
  <tr class="child nosort"><td>1 Child</td></tr>
  <tr class="parent"><td>2 Parent</td></tr>
  <tr class="child nosort"><td>2 Child</td></tr>
  <tr class="parent"><td>3 Parent</td></tr>
  <tr class="child nosort"><td>3 Child</td></tr>
</table>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

but as you know, you could end up also having P2 P1 C1 C2 ... but that was not your question. Otherwise, to tackle with that problem the best would be to go back to the whiteboard, and simply place two `<div>`s inside a `<td>`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I think my answer could help someone out. Here's an updated version of Roko C. Buljan's post.

In this version the children aren't draggable, but the parents are. When one of the parents is dragged the children are temporarily "detached", using the built in .detach() Jquery method, and added to a global obj. Once the parents are finished dragging, than the children are added back to the DOM in the original order.

```js
$('.parent').each(function() {
 $(this).data('$children', $(this).nextUntil('.parent'));
});

var children = {};

$('table').sortable({
  items: 'tr:not(.nosort)',
  start: function() {
    $('.parent').each(function() {
       children[this.id] = $($(this).data('$children')).detach()
    });
  },
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    $('.parent').each(function() {
       $(this).after(children[this.id]);
    });
  }
});
```

```css
td {
  padding: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<table style="padding: 1rem">
  <tr class="parent red" id="one"><td>1 Parent</td></tr>
  <tr class="child nosort red"><td>1 Child</td></tr>
  <tr class="parent blue" id="two"><td>2 Parent</td></tr>
  <tr class="child nosort blue"><td>2 Child</td></tr>
  <tr class="parent green" id="three"><td>3 Parent</td></tr>
  <tr class="child nosort green"><td>3 Child</td></tr>
  <tr class="child nosort green"><td>3 Child</td></tr>
  <tr class="child nosort green"><td>3 Child</td></tr>
</table>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).